# Workflow task status check not triggering

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer

I have a pretty simple 2013 SharePoint Designer workflow that assigns a task to a user, pauses then go back checks if the task status is set to "incomplete". The column's default value choice is "incomplete" when the tasks are created. However, after the pause, it will not send an overdue email based on the "incomplete" status of the field unless I open the task and deliberately set the field as "incomplete".  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: what does your "if" statement look like?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly your workflow is doing?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  @Flat Banana Just added a screenshot above. It's obviously still in testing mode.

Comment: @wjervis Basically the workflow is attached to a list. When an item is added to the list it assigns a task to the staff member in the list item and waits for a period of time, then checks if the status of the task still equals "incomplete" which is the default value when the item is created. If it is incomplete, it sends a reminder email to the staff member.  For some reason it only fires off the reminder email if I go into the task and manually click "incomplete".  It's like the default value "incomplete" isn't triggering the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you edit the `Task Status` Choice field and you added "Incomplete" status ! where the default `Task Status` values are

- Not Started
- In Progress
- Completed
- Deferred
- Waiting on someone else

With the default value is `Not Started` , So I think no need to add a new  `Incomplete` option, just set your condition like as

```
If Association: Task List:Task Status not equals Completed
```

It's the same meaning with the default provided values in `Task Status` Choice field. !